# Grunt Build - Angular: app in dist folder does not work

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I develope an angular app. After building with grunt build, the app in the dist folder does not work on mobile devices (tablet, phone, smart tv) only on PC.
It only loads the background of the page. It is strange, because if I deploy the app folder (so the whole project) it will be loaded..

```
'use strict';
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
    return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // load all grunt tasks
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // configurable paths
    var yeomanConfig = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    try {
        yeomanConfig.app = require('./bower.json').appPath || yeomanConfig.app;
    } catch (e) {
    }

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        yeoman: yeomanConfig,
        watch: {
            coffee: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:dist']
            },
            coffeeTest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
                tasks: ['coffee:test']
            },
            compass: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass']
            },
            livereload: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,**/}*.{html,json}',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,**/}*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,**/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,**/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'

                ],
                tasks: ['livereload']
            }
        },
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            lrSnippet,
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'test')
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        open: {
            server: {
                url: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
            }
        },
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        dot: true,
                        src: [
                            '.tmp',
                            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            },

            unitWatch: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: false
            }
        },
        coffee: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                        src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                        dest: '.tmp/scripts',
                        ext: '.js'
                    }
                ]
            },
            test: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'test/spec',
                        src: '{,*/}*.coffee',
                        dest: '.tmp/spec',
                        ext: '.js'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        compass: {
            options: {
                sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
                imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
                //fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
                //importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components',
                relativeAssets: true
            },
            dist: {
                cssDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'

            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    //debugInfo: true
                }
            }
        },
        concat: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
                        '.tmp/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
            }
        },
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                        src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                        '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                     // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                     //collapseWhitespace: true,
                     collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                     removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                     removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                     useShortDoctype: true,
                     removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                     removeOptionalTags: true*/
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                        src: ['*.html', 'views/*.html'],
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
            }
        },
        ngmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts',
                        src: '*.js',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        copy: {
            compass: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: ['main.css'],
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/',
                        filter: 'isFile',
                        expand: true,
                        flatten: true,
                        cwd: '.tmp/styles/'
                    }
                ]
            },

            conf: {
                files: [
                    {
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                        src: 'conf/*.json',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                        expand: true
                    }
                ]
            },

            dist: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        dot: true,
                        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                        src: [
                            '*.{ico,txt}',
                            '.htaccess',
                            'components/**/*',
                            'images/{,*/}*.{gif,webp}',
                            'styles/fonts/*'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        compress: {
            main: {
                options: {
                    archive: 'archive/<%= pkg.name %>_<%= pkg.version %>.zip',
                    mode: 'zip'
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true, src: '**/*', cwd: 'dist/'
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        bump: {
            options: {
                files: ['package.json', 'bower.json'],
                updateConfigs: ['pkg'],
                commit: true,
                commitMessage: 'Release v%VERSION%',
                commitFiles: ['-a'],
                createTag: true,
                tagName: 'v%VERSION%',
                tagMessage: 'Version %VERSION%',
                push: true,
                pushTo: 'origin'
            }
        },
        'string-replace': {
            version: {
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/main.html': '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/main.html'
                },
                options: {
                    replacements: [
                        {
                            pattern: /{{ VERSION }}/g,
                            replacement: '<%= pkg.version %>'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.renameTask('regarde', 'watch');

    grunt.registerTask('server', [
        'clean:server',
        'coffee:dist',
        'compass:server',
        'livereload-start',
        'connect:livereload',
        'open',
        'watch',
        'karma:unitWatch'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'coffee',
        'compass',
        'connect:test',
        'karma:unit'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'coffee',
        'compass:dist',
        'copy:compass',
        'useminPrepare',
        'imagemin',
        'cssmin',
        'htmlmin',
        'concat',
        'copy',
        'ngmin',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'string-replace:version',
        'compress'
    ]);

    /*
     Make a patch Release:
     - increment version number
     - build
     - commit to git and create tag vor version
     */
    grunt.registerTask('patch', [
        //'test',
        'bump-only:patch',
        'build',
        'bump-commit'
    ]);

    /*
     Make a minor Release:
     - increment version number
     - build
     - commit to git and create tag vor version
     */
    grunt.registerTask('release-minor', [
        //'test',
        'bump-only:minor',
        'build',
        'bump-commit'
    ]);

    /*
     Make a major Release:
     - increment version number
     - build
     - commit to git and create tag vor version
     */
    grunt.registerTask('release-major', [
        //'test',
        'bump-only:major',
        'build',
        'bump-commit'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work on mobile? Does it work on PC? Did you try remote debugging and check if the you are using a method or a JavaScript function that isn't supported by the device you are trying to test on? Do you realize that this is a problem that might have nothing to do with gruntjs or yeoman?

Comment: Also, can you deploy the output somewhere so we could see the actual problem?

Comment: Thats an intern project, so I cannot deploy it anywhere. If I deploy the app folder on the server, it does load on any devices, but if I deploy the dist folder, it only works on PC. Which JS methods could not be supported in all devices but PC?

Edit: I dont think it happens an unsupported call, because the website will be correctly loaded from the app folder on all devices.

Comment: You need to debug it remotely, perhapse a file is not being copied to your dist directory or something fails during the build. You have to check the console for errors.